# Why does my laptop use so much memory right after powering on?

Tags: windows-10

I have an ASUS laptop and I am trying to figure out why the memory usage is always very high: 93-98% all the time.

Below is usage after restarting and opening one Firefox tab:

[image]

I see that there are numerous instances of java.exe running eating a huge chunk of memory. Anyone know what the program is and how to disable it?

[image]

Startup program screenshot:

[image]

My RAM is 10GB + 2GB taken up by AMD GPU.
Windows 10

Comment: You should investigate what application Tomcat is serving. Also note that Tomcat is running with highest permissions, this is not recommended. Tomcat is running as a Windows Service, so it will not show up as a startup program.

Comment: @DanielB SAP B1 uses Tomcat (see below).

Comment: You cropped out all the interesting stuff in Task Manager's Performance tab.

Comment: The reason your system is using so much memory is due to SAP Business One being installed.  I must admit I am confused by the fact, you seemingly confirmed you are using a Java based web application, but don't recognize the fact that requires Java to be installed on the system.  **My suggestion to resolve the problem would be to simply install more memory in the system.**  You can also increase the size of the page file. However, that will come at a performance penalty, which you might notice.

Comment: @Ramhound Poor wording, didn't think SAP alone was responsible for all those java.exe instances, it is.

Answer (score 2):

[Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) is a programming language. [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) is a program that provides a HTTP web server in which Java applications can run.

If you open the Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and go to the Startup tab you can enable and disable programs that start when you start your computer.

Can you make a screenshot of that, and post it here (you can edit the question)? Then we can tell you which program it probably is so you can disable it.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau Try disabling SAP Business One. This will only stop it from automatically starting when the computer starts, you can still run it whenever you want. Then reboot and check if the problem is gone.

Comment: I use this laptop specifically for SAP B1. The software runs slow on the machine and was hoping there were some other programs I could shut down to get a better SAP experience.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau They have a knowledge base article about slow performance, but I can't read it because it requires a SAP Support Launchpad account (but maybe you can) https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/3107985

Comment: SAP runs on/with tomcat, looks like. It is still worthwhile to try taking it out of auto-runs for troubleshooting. If the the problem doesn't resolve, you know that item isn;t the source of the issue

Comment: @Gantendo, I have gone through SAP material for trouble shooting, I may just have to un-install some SAP components that I will rarely use.

Comment: You can check the memory setting of the SQL server (maybe too much memory is allocated to it). https://www.vision33.com/hubfs/Membership%20Site%20Full%20Resources/How%20to%20Check%20SQL%20Server%20Memory%20Allocation%20for%20SAP%20B1.pdf You can check if the log file is huge (which would slow down writing to it). (e.g. with something like WinDirStat) or https://answers.sap.com/questions/4996084/what-makes-the-sbo-commonlog-grow.html

Comment: This I have not checked. Using SQL Server 2019. Will do.

Comment: Ram is pretty affordable nowadays. If you go to, for example, crucial.com and select your laptop they will tell you which type of RAM is compatible. 16GB seems to be the recommended minimum nowadays for this application. You could stop Google Drive, Dropbox and OneDrive from starting when your computer starts, but it is very likely that won't make much of a difference since SAP B1 is the culprit.

Comment: Note that you can shrink the SAP B1 database https://answers.sap.com/questions/6024903/shrink-database.html but please make backups first!

Comment: It is possible that your log file is gigantic, you can shrink that too https://answers.sap.com/questions/13019144/how-to-shrink-sap-b1-database-log-file-which-has-m.html Again, backups backups backups. You can use WinDirStat to see if this is the case.

Comment: My ASUS maxes out at 12GB so maybe will get a new one soon. Log files are OK. Uninstalling some SAP features has helped.

Comment: @Gantendo - What does the log size have to do with memory usage?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing. But having a huge log file is one of the things that can slow down SAP B1 and OP stated it "runs slow on the machine" (which is not surprising in this case).